# Cocos2d game reboots itself when returning from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1` game. A tester has found a strange issue. The steps:

- Open the game
- Press home button
- Open Safari
- Return to the game

Very often, this will cause the game to **reboot**. Not exactly crash: the game doesn't close itself - it just *restarts* from the splash screen. I myself am unable to reproduce this, but the tester has the following info:

- Occurs on iOS 6 and 7
- Doesn't seem to be device-specific: occurs on iPhone 4, 4s, 5... and iPods and iPads too.
- It seems like opening a different app (like Safari) is **necessary** to reproduce this. If you simply press the home button and reopen the app, it won't reboot itself.
- It is very unlikely that this is due to a memory error - this error can be reproduced on the title screen of the game, which is pretty light.
- The devices are NOT jailbroken.
- Occurs regardless of whether you're logged into Game Center or not.

The tester has a log, and the most eye-catching fact about it is this:

```
Arthurs-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mobile.installation_proxy[4825]) <Notice>: (com.apple.mobile.installation_proxy) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Arthurs-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mobile.installation_proxy[4825]) <Error>: (com.apple.mobile.installation_proxy) assertion failed: 11D257: launchd + 35833 [1A6C526C-3CCA-3E32-B3C0-F448B1D16C89]: 0x9
Arthurs-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sandboxd[4818]) <Notice>: (com.apple.sandboxd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
```

And several lines that are pretty much the same thing. As you can observe, iOS seems to be jettisoning apps, suggesting that there is a lack of memory. However, this is very odd, because

- The tester **doesn't have other apps in the background**.
- The game **doesn't have any memory warnings**, especially since you can reproduce this error on the title screen itself, which doesn't really allocate much at all.

So it is hardly believable that iOS needs to do this at all.

My best bet seems to be checking out `AppDelegate` - after all, here are the method implementations for when the app enters/exits the foreground.

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
    [[GameManager sharedManager] refreshInterface];   // Just update the interface
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}
```

And it all seems to be in order.

What could be happening, then?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest explanation: Safari needs a lot of memory. Therefore iOS decides to close unneeded background apps to free more memory.

Overall you needn't worry about this happening because **it can happen at any time on any device**. Even users themselves can forcefully close background apps. Double-tap the home button, then swipe up on the preview image of the application to terminate it.

It doesn't seem to be an error but rather normal iOS behavior. What you need to do is to ensure that the app - when it was terminated while being in the background - doesn't lose any important data such as in-app progress. At worst the player may need to restart from the checkpoint or level that was last started, but the app shouldn't revert back to, say, level 1.

You should probably implement [`applicationWillTerminate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:) in order to perform any last-minute householding steps.

Comment: Makes sense, but, even in an iPhone 5S? Shouldn't it have enough memory to hold onto at least two apps (Safari and my Game on title screen)? Especially since I am pretty much unable to reproduce this even with a simple iPhone 4!

Comment: @Voldemort Consider the fact that this seems to be happening to only one tester.

Comment: @duci9y: Well, some few people reported this too. Definitely a minority (from 100 probably 6), but it is so strange.

Comment: @Voldemort I think the only way you'd be able to test it is when you have the device in hand. Maybe have the memory usage be logged.

Comment: We don't really know all the reasons why a background app might be closed. It could even be a bug in iOS that occurs only on some devices, or an undetected defect of the device. The thing is: it can happen, and it will happen, even if it is unlikely. Just like, for instance, touches being cancelled due to an incoming sms.